# How to return Generic type as strong typed type

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0, polymorphism

I am porting some Delphi code to C# on a system where I can read different kind of fields from the same source.  I would like to use a parent class and encapsulate all internal way of do on child classes to hide the internal and concrete mechanism of every field type.

I have done a simple example to show where is "my problem":

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ParentField<int> fieldInteger = new MyIntField<int>();
            fieldInteger.Value = 12;

            ParentField<string> fieldString = new MyStringField<string>();
            fieldString.Value = "This is a String";

            Console.WriteLine("1. The Integer Value: " + fieldInteger.Value);
            Console.WriteLine("1. The String Value: " + fieldString.Value);

            int localInteger = fieldInteger.GetRealStrongTypedValue;
            string localString = fieldString.GetRealStrongTypedValue;

            Console.WriteLine("2. The Integer Value: " + localInteger);
            Console.WriteLine("2. The String Value: " + localString);
        }
    }







    public abstract class ParentField<T>
    {
        public abstract Object Value { get; set; }
        public abstract T GetRealStrongTypedValue { get; }
    }

    public sealed class MyIntField<T> : ParentField<T>
    {
        public override Object Value
        {
            get { return valor; }
            set { valor =  (int)value; }
        }
        public override T GetRealStrongTypedValue
        {
            get { return valor; }  // ERROR...
        }

        private int valor;
    }

    public sealed class MyStringField<T> : ParentField<T>
    {
        public override Object Value
        {
            get { return valor; }
            set { valor = (string)value; }
        }
        public override T GetRealStrongTypedValue
        {
            get { return valor; } // ERROR...

        }

        private string valor;
    }
}
```

Also I have tried removing Generic from child `GetRealStrongTypedValue` instance method, in this way:

```
public sealed class MyStringField<T> : ParentField<T>
{
    public override Object Value
    {
        get { return valor; }
        set { valor = (string)value; }
    }
    public new string GetRealStrongTypedValue
    {
        get { return valor; }
    }

    private string valor;
}
```

But then the error is I am not implementing abstract method from `ParentField` Class.

I have tried to change `ParentField.GetRealStrongTypedValue` to virtual, implementing fake content, but polymorphism doesn't run at all and always is using the exact `ParentField.GetRealStrongTypedValue` so it is returning fake content.

Any simple and smart idea ?  :-)

Thanks...

Comment: Why not just keeping it as `T`?

Comment: Because then I must to cast every time in the "consumer" code.  It is only for convenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is not make `MyStringField` generic, but rather make it a type-specific implementation of `ParentField<T>`.

```
public sealed class MyStringField : ParentField<string>
{
    public override Object Value
    {
        get { return valor; }
        set { valor = (string)value; }
    }
    public override string GetRealStrongTypedValue
    {
        get { return valor; } // ERROR...

    }

    private string valor;
}
```

Comment: You are explained what I want better than myself.  Thanks a lot that is...  :-)